# Parent / Child SQL Query - Get All Parent and Children

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Transaction table that tracks all the details of a transaction, and each transaction can have a related transaction. I am having trouble with a query to find all transactions in a pool of related transactions.

Example: 
2 tables: Transactions and RelatedTransactions

RelatedTransactions has a TransactionID and a RelatedTransactionID

Say I have 5 transactions
1 is related to 2
2 is related to 3
3 is related to 4
4 is related to 5

TransactionID RelatedTransactionID
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5

I want a query from the RelatedTransaction table, that will return 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 if supplied the ID 1 (or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5)

It seemed simple at first... I had a query

```
SELECT RelatedTransactionID FROM RelatedTransactions WHERE TransactionID = 1
```

It obviously works when all the related transactions have 1 as the parent transaction.

So, the next thing I added was the opposite to get all the ones where TransID 1 was the related transaction

I added

```
SELECT TransactionID WHERE RelatedTransactionID = 1
```

That worked until the relationships went deeper.

I went from there and added a Temp Table to help me out.

```
create table #RTS (TransactionID int );
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated tr WHERE tr.RelatedTransactionID = @ID;
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.RelatedTransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated tr WHERE tr.TransactionID = @ID;
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT @ID;
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated tr WHERE tr.TransactionID IN (SELECT TransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated WHERE RelatedTransactionID = @ID);
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated tr WHERE tr.RelatedTransactionID IN (SELECT TransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated WHERE RelatedTransactionID = @ID);
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated tr WHERE tr.TransactionID IN (SELECT RelatedTransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated WHERE TransactionID = @ID);
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated tr WHERE tr.RelatedTransactionID IN (SELECT RelatedTransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated WHERE TransactionID = @ID);
```

If I was still deeper than that, I was still not getting everything.

So I took that temptable and added queries to get all related transactions to the current transactions.

```
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM #RTS rts INNER JOIN TransactionsRelated tr on tr.RelatedTransactionID = rts.TransactionID;
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.RelatedTransactionID FROM #RTS rts INNER JOIN TransactionsRelated tr on tr.TransactionID = rts.TransactionID;
```

When I realized I still didn't have it all covered, I just did that 3 more times to make sure I would handle them all.  My final query, which is doing its job, is

```
create table #RTS (TransactionID int );

INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated tr WHERE tr.RelatedTransactionID = @ID;
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.RelatedTransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated tr WHERE tr.TransactionID = @ID;
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT @ID;
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated tr WHERE tr.TransactionID IN (SELECT TransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated WHERE RelatedTransactionID = @ID);
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated tr WHERE tr.RelatedTransactionID IN (SELECT TransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated WHERE RelatedTransactionID = @ID);
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated tr WHERE tr.TransactionID IN (SELECT RelatedTransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated WHERE TransactionID = @ID);
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated tr WHERE tr.RelatedTransactionID IN (SELECT RelatedTransactionID FROM TransactionsRelated WHERE TransactionID = @ID);
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM #RTS rts INNER JOIN TransactionsRelated tr on tr.RelatedTransactionID = rts.TransactionID;
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.RelatedTransactionID FROM #RTS rts INNER JOIN TransactionsRelated tr on tr.TransactionID = rts.TransactionID;
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM #RTS rts INNER JOIN TransactionsRelated tr on tr.RelatedTransactionID = rts.TransactionID;
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.RelatedTransactionID FROM #RTS rts INNER JOIN TransactionsRelated tr on tr.TransactionID = rts.TransactionID;
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM #RTS rts INNER JOIN TransactionsRelated tr on tr.RelatedTransactionID = rts.TransactionID;
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.RelatedTransactionID FROM #RTS rts INNER JOIN TransactionsRelated tr on tr.TransactionID = rts.TransactionID;
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.TransactionID FROM #RTS rts INNER JOIN TransactionsRelated tr on tr.RelatedTransactionID = rts.TransactionID;
INSERT INTO #RTS SELECT tr.RelatedTransactionID FROM #RTS rts INNER JOIN TransactionsRelated tr on tr.TransactionID = rts.TransactionID;

SELECT DISTINCT t.ID, t.CreateDate, t.TransactionDate, t.Amount, t.TypeID, t.SourceID, t.UserID, ts.Name as Source, tt.Name as TypeName, t.Subject 
FROM Transactions t INNER JOIN #RTS r on r.TransactionID = t.ID INNER JOIN TransactionSources ts on t.SourceID = ts.ID INNER JOIN TransactionTypes tt on tt.ID = t.TypeID ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC

DROP TABLE #RTS;
```

This works as is, but I assume that if a transaction has 20+ levels of relations, it might not reach them.

Now that the product is functional, what I really want to know is if there is someway to better recursively do this in SQL (MSSQL/Azure if it matters).  There has to be a better way.

Comment: Do related transactions form trees or just chains?

Comment: No trees or hierarchy, only chains.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a recursive query.

In SQL Server 2005 and above you can write it using Common Table Expressions

E.g.

```
WITH RecursiveTransactions AS

(

SELECT RelatedTransactionID, TransactionID FROM RelatedTransactions WHERE RelatedTransactionID IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT RelatedTransactionID, TransactionID FROM RelatedTransactions a JOIN RecursiveTransactions cte ON cte.TransactionID  = a.RelatedTransactionID

)

SELECT RelatedTransactionID, TransactionID FROM RecursiveTransactions 
WHERE TransactionID  = @ID
```

If your DBMS doesnt support CTE then you can write a recursive SP which will basically take @id as input and call itself with relatedID as @id

```
Example:

CREATE PROCEDURE RECURSIVETRANSACTIONID  AS
(@ID int)
BEGIN

IF #temp does not exists then
CREATE #temp
END IF


INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT RelatedTransactionID, TransactionID FROM RecursiveTransactions 
WHERE TransactionID  = @ID


IF(@id is not null) then -- this check makes sure it terminates when relation is not found (i.e. for last element)
EXEC RECURSIVETRANSACTIONID(SELECT RelatedTransactionID FROM #temp)


END
```

Comment: If you want to format text as code, just select the text and press the `{}` button

Comment: This looks great, it gives me something to go off of, the problem I see is that my query doesn't really have a base case.  In your example there has to be an ultimate top level parent where the RelatedTransactionID is null, correct?

In my case, there is no set top level, there are just transactions that can arbitrarily be related to any other transaction.

Comment: In that case what output do you expect? Do the transaction relation for any pattern (e.g. circle) like 1 refer to 2, 2 to 3 and 3 back to 1? Any query needs a stopping point which tells it to stop bringing data (a condition, a loop counter). Whats the stopping point here? I mean if you want to read data from Transactions table with its related data there should be some stopping point otherwise you will just end up getting all the data in the table.

Comment: I am trying to find all of the transactions that have some sort of relation, that one specific group. Say Transaction ID #1 and #2 are related, I would expect the results to be 1, 2.  If #3 is related to #4, and #4 is related to #6 and #6 is related to #10, I would want #3, #4, #6 and #10. One complete family or group

Comment: Ok are all the transactions in your table related to each other? if so then above logic will just end up getting all the rows.. like #10 would be related to #11 and #11 to #12 and so forth.. You need to identify a stopping point (e.g. reaching a max transaction number) or something else.